# Não consigo carregar a imagem no carossel

Tags: react-native

Tenho uma tela home com um carrossel, onde cada item tem um titulo e uma imagem, entretanto a imagem não renderiza de jeito nenhum, apenas o título. Eu não tô conseguindo identificar porque isso tá ocorrendo, já que a URL das imagens está correta.

**Home**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import styles from "./styles";

import {
   View, 
   Text,
   Dimensions,
   Image
} from "react-native";

import {
   NavigationParams,
   NavigationScreenProp,
   NavigationState
} from 'react-navigation';

import Carousel from "react-native-snap-carousel";
import { ScrollView } from "react-native-gesture-handler";

const primeiroItem = 1;

const dados = [
{
    title: 'Beautiful and dramatic Antelope Canyon',
    subtitle: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et nuncat mergitur',
    illustration: 'https://i.imgur.com/UYiroysl.jpg'
},
{
    title: 'Earlier this morning, NYC',
    subtitle: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
    illustration: 'https://i.imgur.com/UPrs1EWl.jpg'
},
{
    title: 'White Pocket Sunset',
    subtitle: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et nuncat ',
    illustration: 'https://i.imgur.com/MABUbpDl.jpg'
},
]

const width = Dimensions.get("screen").width;

interface Props {
    navigation: NavigationScreenProp<NavigationState, NavigationParams>;
 }

export default class Home extends Component<Props> {
constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        slider1ActiveSlide: primeiroItem
    };
}

_renderItem ({item, index}) {
    return (
        <View>
            <Image
                source={{ uri: item.illustration }}
            />
            <Text>{ item.title }</Text>
        </View>
    );
  }

render() {
    return(
        <ScrollView>
                <Carousel
                    data={dados}
                    renderItem={this._renderItem}
                    sliderWidth={width}
                    itemWidth={width}
                    autoplay={true}
                    autoplayDelay={500}
                    autoplayInterval={3000}
                    firstItem={primeiroItem}
                    onSnapToItem={(index) => this.setState({ slider1ActiveSlide: index }) }
                />
        </ScrollView>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução para seu problema é simples. Imagens sem a especificação de largura [width](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props#width) e altura [height](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props#height) não são mostradas pelo react native, ou seja, sempre que se utilizar o `<Image/`> temos de setar o seu tamanho.

Alterando o código, basta trocarmos:

```
_renderItem ({item, index}) {
    return (
        <View>
            <Image
                source={{ uri: item.illustration }}
            />
            <Text>{ item.title }</Text>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Por:

```
 _renderItem({ item, index }) {
     return (
         <View>
             <Image 
                 source={{ uri: item.illustration }} 
                 style={{ width: 300, height: 300}} />
             <Text>{item.title}</Text>
         </View>
     );
 }
```

**Obs: Tomando por base que queira utilizar um tamanho padrão de 300x300 para todas as imagens.**

Pode-se utilizar as medidas da maneira que for necessária. [Mais sobre o componente Image](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image).

Dica: Para que a imagem fique melhor redimensionada no espaço que deseja incorpora-lá, utilize o método [resizeMode](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image#resizemode) que determina como redimensionar a imagem quando o espaço não corresponde ao tamanho da imagem.

**[Link da solução](https://snack.expo.io/@sant0will/813e21)**

Comment: Consegui resolver, obrigada! Não sabia que o width e heigth era necessário para renderizar as imagens no React Native